# EF4 ExecuteStoreQuery get nested lists

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I've a stored procedure that has 3 select statements:

```
select col1, col2 from table1
select col1, col2 from table2
select col1, col2 from table3
```

I've created 3 models for each table as:

```
public class table1
{
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
}
public class table2
{
    public int col1 { get; set; }
    public int col2 { get; set; }
}
public class table3
{
    public decimal col1 { get; set; }
    public decimal col2 { get; set; }
}
```

And then another model that contains lists of these models like:

```
public class mymodel
{
    public IEnumerable<table1> table1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<table2> table2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<table3> table3 { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to fill `mymodel` by:

```
var model = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<mymodel>("sproc1").FirstOrDefault();
```

But `mymodel` always have `null` for `table1`,`table2` and `table3`.

How can I achieve this? Does EF4 support it?

Comment: You have 3 stored procs? Or one stored proc that fires 3 SQL statements?

Comment: only one stored proc, not 3

Comment: A potentially related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086506/entity-framework-stored-procedure-with-multiple-resultsets

Comment: It is not supported. `ExecuteStoreQuery` cannot return entity with relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return 3 result sets from the stored procedure in EF. You need to split the stored procedure up into separate stored procs, each of which returns a result set (table). Then you can get at those results

OR perhaps you could change your sproc to return one result set that is a UNION of the 3 select statements, so that they can be read -

```
select col1, col2 from table1 UNION
select col1, col2 from table2 UNION
select col1, col2 from table3
```

**EDIT**

Apparently it IS supported now with EF 5 - see here for info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402

Comment: I think UNION wont be good idea in my case as all 3 tables in my proc have totally different schema. 3 procs can be a work around but my model will be populated in 3 db calls mean costly. And finally, my project has already been about 80% completed in EF4 so I am not in position to switch from EF4 to EF5.

Comment: IME, going from EF4 to EF5 is quite minor, there are not that many breaking changes (if any) - spike it for an hour, you might find it's simple.

Comment: Will it target my .NET framework too? I am using 4.0. Will I need to switch to 4.5 to use EF5? I cant change my framework, unfortunately.

Comment: Its partially support in .net 4 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594289/are-there-technical-reasons-ef-5-isnt-fully-supported-on-net4-0),

Comment: I think rather than going for that, ADO.NET DataSet would be better option in this case. :)